# Show Sum of 2 Textboxes in 3rd Textbox

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to do a direct calculation but it doesn't work.

This is what I have at the moment.

```
Private Sub TextBox270_AfterUpdate() 
    TextBox270.Value = Val(TextBox1.Value) + Val(TextBox150.Value)    
End Sub
```

I am trying to achive

```
1 (in TextBox1) + 2 (in TextBox150) = 3 (in TextBox270)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the change event of `TextBox1` and `Textbox150`

Is this what you are trying? (**Untested**) I am assuming that you **will** be entering valid numbers in those two textboxes.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    GenerateSum
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox150_Change()
    GenerateSum
End Sub

Sub GenerateSum()
    If Len(Trim(TextBox1.Text)) <> 0 And _
       Len(Trim(TextBox150.Text)) <> 0 Then

        TextBox270.Text = Val(Trim(TextBox1.Text)) + _
                        Val(Trim(TextBox150.Text))

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You are simply the Best))Thanks a lot))) working welll